# How do I form a parameter string with multiple values and check whether a ? or & is needed for the value?

Tags: php

I have a form that gives a lot of different options via dropdown selectors.  Like :

```
<!--// height //-->
<option value='3918'>5'7"</option>
<option value='3917'>5'8"</option>
<option value='3916'>5'9"</option>
<option value='3915'>5'10"</option>

<!--// weight //-->
<option value='3913'>101-120lbs</option>
<option value='3912'>121-140lbs</option>
<option value='3911'>141-160lbs</option>
<option value='3910'>161-180lbs</option>
```

I need to associate those numbers with another variable that allows filtering from thte url parameters.  SO for example I have a switch statement like :

```
if (isset($form['height'])){
        $hv = $wizard['height'];
        $hvr = '4\'0"';
        $hvd = 0;
        switch ( $hv ) 
            {
            case 3915 : $hvd= 4294964526; $hvr = '5\'10"'; break;
            case 3916 : $hvd= 4294964528; $hvr = '5\'9"'; break;
            case 3917 : $hvd= 4294964529; $hvr = '5\'8"'; break;
            case 3918 : $hvd= 4294964406; $hvr = '5\'7"'; break;
            }
     }

if (isset($wizard['weight'])){
    $wv = $wizard['weight'];
    $wvr = '100 lbs';
    $wvd = 0;
    switch ( $wv ) 
    {
        case 3910 : $wvd = 4294964413; $wvr = '161-180 lbs'; break;
        case 3911 : $wvd = 4294964421; $wvr = '141-160 lbs'; break;
        case 3912 : $wvd = 4294964422; $wvr = '121-140 lbs'; break;
        case 3913 : $wvd = 4294964400; $wvr = '121-140 lbs'; break;
    }
}
```

The variable being generated in the switch is what needs to be appended at the end of the url parameters.

So for example a correct url from this submission of a 5'7" 150lb would look along the lines of :

```
site.com?height=3918&weight=3911&d=4294964421,4294964406
```

Now I need to pass these into a url parameter to redirect to when form is submitted.

So to start I guess I need to build that string in each individual `if(isset)`?  So for just height I would have

`$this->getResponse()->setRedirect( "site.com?height=" . $hv ."&d=" . $hvd );`

but what would be the best way to build these strings with multiple POST values?  How do I check if there needs to be a `?` or `&` for that value in the parameter?  How would I check if a `,` is necessary when there are multiple d values?

Answer (score 0):

Have an array that holds your query string variables.

```
$variables = array();
```

Then add the variables as needed to the array.

```
$variables [] = "height=3918"; 
$variables [] = "weight=3911";
```

Then to construct your query string, you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which will "glue" together the variables with `&`

```
$query_string = ''; 
if( count( $variables ) > 0 )
{
    $query_string .= '?'.implode('&', $variables);  
}
```